# how to send automatic email from android app through cpanel mail server

Tags: android, email, server

> I want to send my customers password with email to them?
>   My server is linux server(Cpanel).
>   I know how to make relation between android and my sql(php).
>   but i dont know how to make mail server and connect php web service to it?

Answer (score 0):

1. We can use PHP Mailer to send and email using PHP and you can integrate with your PHP web services.
2. we can use send grid library to send email from android mobile

   [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/)

   **Example :**

   SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("SENDGRID USERNAME", "SENDGRID_PASSWORD");

   SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
   email.addTo("example@example.com");
   email.setFrom("other@example.com");
   email.setSubject("Hello World");
   email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

   try {
     SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
     System.out.println(response.getMessage());
   }
   catch (SendGridException e) {
     System.err.println(e);
   }